# Login_form add to top of form rather then bottom

Tags: custom-field, login, forms

I have added a 3rd field on the login page, but it shows at the bottom(underneath password) while I would like it to show above Username.

How can I manipulate the order of fields?

This is the code I have used to add the field.

```
add_action('login_form', 'add_login_auth');
function add_login_auth() {
    $klantnr = (isset($_POST['klantnr'])) ? $_POST['klantnr'] : '';
    ?>
        <p>
        <label for="klantnr">Klantnummer<br>
        <input type="text" tabindex="20" size="10" value="" class="input" id="klantnr" name="klantnr"></label>
        </p>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: There is no hook for above the fields (see the source of `wp-login.php`) - afraid you'll have to resort to JS to move it.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer I'd get :( I'm absolutely no expert on JS. Do you know how to do this with JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no hook for above the fields (perhaps you might want to submit a patch/feature request on [trac](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/)?)

You'll have to get by with JavaScript:

```
<p id="klantnr-field">
    <label for="klantnr">Klantnummer<br>
    <input type="text" tabindex="20" size="10" value="" class="input" id="klantnr" name="klantnr"></label>
 </p>

<script>
    (function ( form ) {
        form.insertBefore( document.getElementById( "klantnr-field" ), form.childNodes[0] )
    })( document.getElementById( "loginform" ) );
</script>
```

And I hope you'll be [sanitizing](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) that `$klantnr` variable if you plan on using it ;)

Comment: This worked for 50%, it put the textfield itself on top, but it let the text below the form. And ofcourse I'll sanitize it!

Comment: Wait, I was wrong. It should work if I give the klantnr id to <p>.

Comment: Whoops my bad, fixed.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to change the 'Username or Email' label? I don't plan on giving people usernames so it'll only cause confusion. (I think it came with 4.5?)

Comment: You can either use JavaScript or the popular "dirty" technique is to use the `gettext` filter in PHP and replace it on the fly.

Comment: How could I do this with JS? I don't see it has an id, so I can't specifically target it

Comment: `document.querySelector( "label[for=user_login]" ).childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Email";`